# Expected identifier or "(" before "void"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webkit, browser, void

I am now trying to build a web browser from the tutorial at macdevcenter.com:
http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/05/28/webkit.html?page=3

And I am on the MyDocument.h file part on page 3 that teaches how to set a default homepage. It says that I have to add these prototypes for some accessors used later on in the .m file:

```
(void)setDefaultHomepage:(NSString*); // the error says expected "(" before "void"
-(NSString *)getDefaultHomepage;
```

Can anyone tell me what this means and what I should do about it?

--Thank you!

Comment: In Cocoa you usually don’t have the names of getters start with "get". You also might want to use a `@property` instead of defining the getter and setter manually.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a - in front of (void), you may want to put a variable name after as well

```
-(void) setDefaultHomepage: (NSString*) newhomepage;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a `-` in there:

```
-(void)setDefaultHomepage:(NSString*);
```